# Does coc.nvim can autocomplete known methods' arguments in Python?

Tags: python, vim, coc.nvim

I'm using vim with `coc.nvim` and the `coc-python` plugin.
In Pycharm for example, when I write a contextmanager class like:

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    pass  # some code
  
  def __enter__(self):
    pass  # some code 

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    pass  # some code
```

Then during typing the `__exit__()` method I get the `exc_*` common args autocompleted for me (I know that these names don't have to be these exactly, but it's a convention). Can I get a similar behaviour with `coc.nvim`? Currently it doesn't do that. Same goes for autocompleting `self` at each method which is not a class or a static method.

Comment: Have you considered trying ultisnips? You can custom define whatever snippets you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's called signatureHelp in LSP. It's not recommend to use `coc-python` now because Microsoft Python Language Server will be deprecated in future. You can use [coc-pyright](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright) if you're using Python 3.

[image]

Comment: How do I disable `coc-python` and move to use `coc-pyright` (other than just doing `CocInstall coc-pyright`? Also, when I enter a new class I get the `__init__()` autocompletion but not the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`...

Comment: `CocUninstall coc-python` and `:CocInstall coc-pyright`.

Comment: The `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods still don't get autocompleted

Comment: @Corel can't reproduce, the two methods will be listed in completions list.